# Pandas/Python dataframes - Lost in merge logics

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge, right-join

I'm excercising on [this](https://dandelion.eu/datagems/SpazioDati/precipitation-trentino/description/) open dataset. The basic description of used dataframes:

There's one that contains info on data availability: `dataavail`

```
Timestamp    Availability
201605252300 True
201605252315 False
201605252015 True
```

There's one that contains the actual data `weatherdata`

```
SquareID Timestamp    Precipitation
25       201605252300 1
```

The thing is, that if there is *no* rain, that is *not* marked by `weatherdata.Precipitation` being `0`, but by simply missing from `weatherdata`. However, not all data that is missing means no precipitation, it can also mean technical failure. That's where `dataavail` comes in. If for a `Timestamp` in `data` the `Availability` is `False`, that means there was a technical problem and there's no data. If for a `Timestamp` in `data` the `Availability` is `True`, that means the precipitation was actually 0.

I want to combine these two dataframes so that I have a dataframe describing the full spectrum of options, namely one that looks like this:

```
Timestamp    Availability Precipitation
201605252300 True         1            #if the availability is True, and there's rain, data can be pulled from weatherdata
201605252315 False        NaN          #if there's a technical issue, data can stay NaN for further imputation
201605252015 True         0            #if the data's availability is True, but there's no entry fot it in weatherdata, it should be 0
```

Now to achieve this, I'm trying to merge them as

```
precip_alldata = pd.merge(weatherdata, dataavail, on=['Timestamp'], how='right')
```

In my understanding, according to the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) this should

> right: use only keys from right frame (SQL: right outer join)

But that is what I want, since in `dataavail` there's availability data for ALL the possible timestamps. I also understand, that this does not yet substitute NaN's with 0 in case of availability being True. However, the output `precip_alldata` doesn't have ANY rows, where `Availability` is `True`, but `Precipitation` is `NaN`, and that leads me to believe that something's off in my thinking. Looking at the raw dataset, I can clearly see occasions where there was no precipitation and the `Avaiability` is `True`. So my output looks something like

```
Timestamp    Availability Precipitation
201605252300 True         1
201605252315 False        Nan
```

where in my understanding/what I want is

```
Timestamp    Availability Precipitation
201605252300 True         1
201605252315 False        NaN
201605252015 True         NaN
```

in this first step.
Could you please point out the culprit in my thinking? Thank you!

Comment: Does anything change when you do the merge with `on=['Timestamp','Precipitation']`?

Comment: @Khris - this will not work since Precipitation does not exist in both datasets.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
precip_alldata = pd.merge(dataavail, weatherdata, how='left')
precip_alldata[['TimeStamp', 'Availability', 'Precipitation']]
```

Using a left join will give you all rows from the left dataframe (dataavail).

Output:

```
          Timestamp Availability  Precipitation
0  201605252300         True            1.0
1  201605252315        False            NaN
2  201605252015         True            NaN
```

Comment: `precip_alldata = pd.merge(dataavail, weatherdata, how='left')` is literally the same as `precip_alldata = pd.merge(weatherdata,dataavail, how='right')`. Nevertheless, I tried and it yields the same output.

Comment: I replicated your exact datasets above which yielded the copy/pasted output you're looking at. Something else is going on if this doesn't work.